# VSTS Database Project: To refresh dependencies or schema

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs, database-project

I need a hand on creating and using VSTS 2008 Database project?

I have downloaded GDR2 from MS and imported our huge db into a new Database Project. Now, i am able to use full futures of TFS which makes me really happy.

But here is question;

As soon as i check-out an sp from tfs,
i loose the reference of it in
Dependency Viewer.

> > How can i refresh,
> >     or recreate the db schema? (I know it
> >     takes really long to create a schema,
> >     i would appriciate if you have the
> >     answer of this one as well)

Answer (score 1):

So, this is the time! First time i answer my own question. Wonder which badges created for this behavior!

I told you, it is huge system. (dbml file is 1.2 gbytes), so it was not possible (it is possible, but first i have to delete some thousand of sp which are failing) to build it to deploy.

So i was changing the sp scripts "CREATE" to "ALTER" to able to deploy it to db server. This is the only reason, i am loosing the dependency!

Now, i am changing back to "CREATE PROC", before i check-in.

> However, i still expeirience the slow
>   loading solution issue. It creates the
>   schema, eachtime i open the solution.
>   Spliting the solution could be an
>   answer for most of you but not working for me
>   :(

Comment: You shouldn't need to change the "CREATE" at all.

Comment: Yes, but it was the solution. Sorry mate! I think it is kind a bug on 2008.

Comment: @John Saunders: Pardon me, I misunderstood. I have to change the scripts to ALTER since I cannot build DB project(There are many errors.). Now simply running the scripts against db server to apply the changes, Sure after i clear these things up, it is a solution not to change it to CREATE.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is move to VS2010, at least for the database project.  It handles all these little details for you.

Comment: Spend some more money? :) Thanks anyway.